# What is the meaning of "ones with a claim ..."?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "ones with a claim ..." ?

The sentence is here

> For the balance of Book II I shall explore this difficulty and examine the uses of this narrower class of ethical arguments, **ones with a claim** to be derived from constitutional rather than moral conventions.

Comment: Required More contexts.

Comment: Jason, replace "ones" with "those arguments"

Answer (score 5):

The author refers to 'a narrower class of ethical arguments' and then goes on to specify what this 'narrower class' is - '[arguments] with a claim to be derived from constitutional rather than moral conventions'.

Using *ones* is a common way of avoiding repetition in a sentence.

> There were lots of geranium plants on sale, but I chose the ones with the most flowers.

Comment: Personally, I think the cited usage looks a bit sloppy / colloquial. In a more formal context, I'd expect ***those** with a claim...* Plus I'd use a semicolon (perhaps a dash) rather than a comma, but maybe that's because I'm an old fuddy-duddy. It's commas all the way down these days.

Comment: Just as Fumble says.  It's basically a typo for "those ...", any editor would change it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Semi-colon doesn't work, the part beginning with "ones" is not a complete clause (it has no verb). It's just a noun phrase describing the "narrower class".

Comment: @Barmar: I don't really care about punctuation marks, since real language is spoken anyway. The important point is I'd much prefer the ***word*** "those" over "ones" in the cited context (where "those ones" is overkill, and plain "ones" is a bit casual). But maybe you wouldn't cavil at an actual ***colon.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think this is a _perfect_ case for a colon, as it's introducing a definition or explanation of what went before it.